# Why not replace reflection by bounded reflection in Muller's approach?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

**Bounded Reflection:** If $\phi$ is a formula in the language of set theory [i.e.; $\small \sf FOL(=,\in)$], in which all and only symbols $``x,x_1,..,x_n"$ occur free, and $\phi^V$ is the formula obtained by merely bounding all quantifiers in $\phi$ by $V$, then all closures of: $$x_1,..,x_n \in V \land \exists x (\phi) \to \exists x \in V (\phi^V) $$; are axioms.

Now if we add this principle to the axioms of **Extensionality** and **$\subset$-Closure**, that is: $V$ is closed under subclass relation $\subset$; and **Separation** [using any formula], and **Regularity**, both over all classes. Then it appears to me that $V \models ZF$

> My question here is: does this theory prove that $V$ is inaccessible?

I personally suspect that it does *not*. My point here is that if my suspicion turns to be true, then this theory would have been the one that most capture [Muller's](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF) principles about a foundational theory for mathematics, rather than just extending Ackermann's class theory with a class separation schema as he did. Since in that case we won't have $V$ being a model of $ZF$, thus lacking a very desirable thing to have if our class theoretic based category theory is to be *sufficient* [in Muller's sense] in capturing set theoretic properties! For example: *sets have a model*!

Note: the symbol $``V"$ is a primitive constant, informally standing for the class of all *sets*, as we are working in the language of Ackermann's set theory.